# What's the best way to test opencv mat datatype against c++ types?

Tags: c++, templates, opencv

I am now trying to implement some functions in opencv lib by my self, such that convert an rgb image to gray scale.

In order to make the function as general as possible, I would to let it be able to handle all the datatypes in open cv (CV_8U, CV_8S, ... CV64F), i.e., the output image datatype should match the input image datatype. This involves defining some pointers that have the save type as the input image datatype.

I understand that figuring out datatype of input and initializing the corresponding pointer cannot be done in runtime, so I have to use some sort of switch to determining it in the code.

In the code, I have a template function `t_convert_RGB_to_Gray<T>(...)` defined for do the actual job. Then I have a poly-function `convert_RGB_to_Gray(...)` to be able to determine the data type and call the right conversion function.

I currently have the following two approaches for the datatype test:

approach 1

```
     switch(image.depth())
    {
        case CV_8U: gray = t_convert_RGB_to_Gray<unsigned char>(image, coeff_R, coeff_G, coeff_B); break;
        case CV_8S: gray = t_convert_RGB_to_Gray<char>(image, coeff_R, coeff_G, coeff_B); break;
        case CV_16U:gray = t_convert_RGB_to_Gray<uint16_t>(image, coeff_R, coeff_G, coeff_B); break;
        case CV_16S:gray = t_convert_RGB_to_Gray<int16_t>(image, coeff_R, coeff_G, coeff_B); break;
        case CV_32S:gray = t_convert_RGB_to_Gray<int32_t>(image, coeff_R, coeff_G, coeff_B); break;
        case CV_32F:gray = t_convert_RGB_to_Gray<float>(image, coeff_R, coeff_G, coeff_B); break;
        case CV_64F:gray = t_convert_RGB_to_Gray<double>(image, coeff_R, coeff_G, coeff_B); break;
        default:    gray = t_convert_RGB_to_Gray<unsigned char>(image, coeff_R, coeff_G, coeff_B); break;
    }
```

approach 2

```
if (cv::DataType<unsigned char>::depth == image.depth())
{
    // variation 1.
    //gray = t_convert_RGB_to_Gray<unsigned char>(image, coeff_R, coeff_G, coeff_B);
    // variation 2.
    gray = t_convert_RGB_to_Gray<cv::DataType<unsigned char>::channel_type>(image, coeff_R, coeff_G, coeff_B);
}
else if
 ....
}
```

My question is, is there any draw back of doing this? Is there any better way for this?

Thank you!

Comment: Approach 1. It's easier to understand and less verbose.

Comment: @ChronoTrigger That was the approach that I first came up with. But after I read more about the cv DataType class, it gives me an impression that it is not necessary, for example for unsigned char to match with CV_8U, as this is up to implementation. So I came up the second way, which loop through c++ types and try to find the counterpart in opencv using its build in functionality.

Comment: @ChronoTrigger ideally, what I would expect is a function, that take a c++ type as parameter, return a cv datatype, i.e. `cv::get_cv_type(float) //return: CV_32F (5)`. Given that I am new to C++ and having a limited understanding of how data type system works in opencv ( especially, what type trait is, and how the enum works as type), Although worked, I am not confident that my second approach is the normal way of doing such thing.

Answer (score 2):

To complete Miki's answer, you can do something similar to your first approach:

```
switch(image.depth()) {
  case DataType<unsigned char>::type:
    gray = t_convert_RGB_to_Gray<unsigned char>(image, coeff_R, coeff_G, coeff_B);
    break;
  case DataType<int>::type:
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> ideally, what I would expect is a function, that take a c++ type as parameter, return a cv datatype, i.e. cv::get_cv_type(float) //return: CV_32F (5).

This can be done using `DataType`, e.g.:

```
DataType<unsigned char>::type   == CV_8UC1 
DataType<char>::type            == CV_8SC1 
DataType<float>::type           == CV_32FC1
DataType<double>::type          == CV_64FC1
DataType<Vec3b>::type           == CV_8UC3 
DataType<Vec<int, 4>>::type     == CV_32SC4
```