# cv::DataType<> versus cv::traits::Type<>

Tags: c++, opencv

As far as I can determine (I cannot find decent documentation, however), in OpenCV 3.3 the `cv::DataType` was replaced by `cv::traits::Type<>`, so to get to compile on both versions I need to do something like this:

```
template <typename T>
void f(cv::Mat &src)
{
    using DstPixel = cv::Vec<T, 3>;

    dst.create(src.rows,
               src.cols,
#if CV_VERSION_MAJOR >= 3 && CV_VERSION_MINOR >= 3
               cv::traits::Type<DstPixel>::value);
#else
               cv::DataType<DstPixel>::type);
#endif
}
```

This looks a little messy, and it seems a bit odd there isn't a backward-compatibility path for a minor version change. Is there a cleaner way of getting code to compile with either version?

(Note that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32412550/1270789) also needs updating to `cv::traits::Type<>`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is to define somewhere in your project `OPENCV_TRAITS_ENABLE_DEPRECATED`
 with
`#define OPENCV_TRAITS_ENABLE_DEPRECATED`
or as a compile option
`-DOPENCV_TRAITS_ENABLE_DEPRECATED`.

If it is defined you can continue to use in your code the old DataType structure:

```
cv::DataType<DstPixel>::type
```

However the new traits system has been introduced to solve some issue related to DataType.
See https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/10115